# Create sub-vectors from matrix

Tags: r

I want to create a vector from the Fold Change column in the following melted matrix. 
One vector for each Pos/Pair. So 4 vectors in this example:

1) Pos 1 and Pair Yes

2) Pos 1 and Pair No

3) Pos 2 and Pair Yes

4) Pos 2 and Pair No

```
Pos Pair    Fold Change
 1  Yes     -0.3617047662
 1  Yes     -0.6392675898
 1  No       0.2679183407
 1  No      -0.0624585384
 2  Yes     -0.9540394046
 2  Yes     -0.4518245284
 2  No      -1.9135873541
 2  No       0.6960538921
 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split` function, it'll give you a list of vectors

```
with(df, split(Fold_Change, list(Pos, Pair)))
# $`1.No`
# [1]  0.26791834 -0.06245854
# 
# $`2.No`
# [1] -1.9135874  0.6960539
# 
# $`1.Yes`
# [1] -0.3617048 -0.6392676
# 
# $`2.Yes`
# [1] -0.9540394 -0.4518245
```